# Databinding doesn't work before Form Load - ComboBox Items initialized only after Form load

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have two ComboBoxes on a winform, one has all the values from a List "MyList" the other I want to have all the values from the selected index of the first, onwards. But I think there is a problem with when items are loaded into the ComboBoxes.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        ComboBox box = new ComboBox();
        box.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
        box.DataSource = MyList.ToList();
        box.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged);
        Tab_Page.Controls.Add(box);

        ComboBox box2 = new ComboBox();
        box2.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
        foreach (object o in box.Items)
            {
                box2.Items.Add(o);
            }
        Tab_Page.Controls.Add(box2);
        box2.Items.RemoveAt(0);
        //This last line throws an error
        //"InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not valid for 'index'."
    }}
```

The error is because box2 has no items in its collection, even though box has all the values from the List at the moment this error is thrown.

So I was wondering how/when exactly are items loaded to the Items collection and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data-binding will not work before the form and control be in [`Created`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.created(v=vs.110).aspx) status and before the form and controls get visible they are not in `Created` status.

The problem here is because of above fact. You are using data-binding to add items to first combo in constructor and as mentioned above, the data-binding will not work there and so in the loop, `Items` collection of first combo is empty yet and no items will be added to second combo.

You can solve the problem using either of these options:

- Add values directly to `Items` of first combo: `box.Items.AddRange(MyList.ToArray());`
- Put the codes in `Shown` or `Load` event of the form.
- Make the form visible before trying to retrieve `Items` of first combo. For example call `this.Show();` after assigning values to `DataSource` of first combo. Calling `this.Show();` or `this.Visible = true;` causes the form and all of its visible controls get `Created`. So the controls should be visible and should be a member of visible part of a visible form.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed and speedy answer! :) it worked with the "AddRange" method, but for educational value - I also tried the "this.Show();" and "this.Visible = true;" way, by putting them before anything else in the Form1() method (or class, or whatever), but it gave the same error.

Comment: You are welcome :) I checked it again.  `this.Visible = true;` or `this.Show();` is main solution when you want to use data-binding. It's enough to put it anywhere before the for loop. I tested exact mcve which you posted. But anyway, the concept is really important and verifiable.