# Databinding one control per row in the same datasource

Tags: vb.net, winforms, data-binding, bindingsource

I've been trying to deal with a frustrating issue with regards to databinding in Winforms.

I have a data source, which is a `DataTable` in a `DataSet`.  This `DataTable` has three rows.  I have three `CheckBox` controls on my form, and a `Button`.  I want to bind each `CheckBox` to one row in this data source, and have the data source reflect the value in the `Checked` property whenever the `CheckBox` is updated.  I also want these changes to be correctly picked up by calls to `HasChanges()` and calls to `GetChanges()`.

When the `Button` is clicked, `EndCurrentEdit()` is called and passed the data-source that was bound to, and the `DataSet` is checked for changes using the `HasChanges()` method.

However, in my attempts to do this, I encounter one of two scenarios after the call to `EndCurrentEdit()`.

In the first scenario, only the first `CheckBox` has its changes detected.  In the second scenario, all other `CheckBoxes` are updated to the value of the `CheckBox` that was last checked on the call to `EndCurrentEdit()`.

In looking at the `RowState` values after the call to `EndCurrentEdit()`, in Scenario 1, only the first row ever has a state of `Modified`.  In Scenario 2, only the third row ever has a state of `Modified`.  For Scenario 2, it doesn't matter whether the user updated the third `CheckBox` or not.

To demonstrate my problem, I have created a simple example which demonstrates it.

It's a stock Windows form containing three `CheckBox` controls and a `Button` control, all with their default names.

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On

Public Class Form1

    Public ds As DataSet

    Public Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

        ds = New DataSet()
        Dim dt As New DataTable()

        dt.Columns.Add("ID", GetType(Integer))
        dt.Columns.Add("Selected", GetType(Boolean))

        dt.Rows.Add(1, False)
        dt.Rows.Add(2, False)
        dt.Rows.Add(3, False)

        dt.TableName = "Table1"

        ds.Tables.Add(dt)

        ds.AcceptChanges()

        For i As Integer = 1 To 3

            Dim bs As New BindingSource()

            'After the call to Me.BindingContext(ds.Tables("Table1")).EndCurrentEdit() there are two scenarios:
            'Scenario 1 - only changes to the first CheckBox are detected.
            'Scenario 2 - when any CheckBox is checked, they all become checked.

            'Uncomment the first and comment out the second to see Scenario 1.
            'Uncomment the second and comment out the first to see Scenario 2.
            'bs.DataSource = New DataView(ds.Tables("Table1")) 'Scenario 1
            bs.DataSource = ds.Tables("Table1") 'Scenario 2
            bs.Filter = "ID=" & i

            Dim db As New Binding("Checked", bs, "Selected")
            db.DataSourceUpdateMode = DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged

            If i = 1
                CheckBox1.DataBindings.Add(db)
            ElseIf i = 2
                CheckBox2.DataBindings.Add(db)
            ElseIf i = 3
                CheckBox3.DataBindings.Add(db)
            End If
        Next
    End Sub


    Private Sub Button1_Click( sender As Object,  e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Me.BindingContext(ds.Tables("Table1")).EndCurrentEdit()

        If ds.HasChanges()
            MessageBox.Show("Number of rows changed: " & ds.GetChanges().Tables("Table1").Rows.Count)
            ds.AcceptChanges()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

I've done a lot of searching but haven't been able to work out what's happening, and am thus at a complete loss.  It feels like what I'm trying to do is pretty simple, but I suspect that I must have misunderstood something somewhere or missed something important with regards to the binding process.

**EDIT**

It's already in the second paragraph, but just to make it clear, here is the basic outline of what I'm trying to do:

1. I have a `DataSet` containing a `DataTable` with values.  For this example, there's two columns.  `ID` could be any `Integer`, 'Selected' could be any `Boolean` value.  None of these will ever be `Nothing` or `DBNull`.
2. I want to bind each row to ONE `Checkbox` control.  One `CheckBox` per `ID` value.  The `Checked` property should be bound to the `Selected` column in the `DataTable`.
3. When changes are made, and the user clicks the `Button`, I want to be able to tell what changes the user made, using the `HasChanges()` and `GetChanges()` methods of the `DataSet` (ie 2 rows updated if the user has changed the `Checked` property of two of the `Checkbox` controls).

**EDIT 2**

Thanks to @RezaAghaei I have come up with a solution.  I have refined the code from my example of the problem, and made all controls generate based on the data (and position themselves accordingly) to make this example simple to copy-and-paste.  Also, this uses a `RowFilter` on the `DataView`, rather than the `Position` property of the `BindingSource`.

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On

Public Class Form1

    Public ds As DataSet

    Private Sub Form1_Load( sender As Object,  e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ds = New DataSet()
        Dim dt As New DataTable()

        dt.Columns.Add("ID", GetType(Integer))
        dt.Columns.Add("Selected", GetType(Boolean))

        dt.Rows.Add(1, False)
        dt.Rows.Add(2, False)
        dt.Rows.Add(3, False)

        dt.TableName = "Table1"
        ds.Tables.Add(dt)
        ds.AcceptChanges()

        AddHandler dt.ColumnChanged,    Sub(sender2 As Object, e2 As DataColumnChangeEventArgs)
                                            e2.Row.EndEdit()
                                        End Sub

        For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count-1
            Dim cb As New CheckBox() With {.Text = "CheckBox" & i+1, .Location = New Point(10, 25 * (i))}

            Dim dv As New DataView(dt)
            dv.RowFilter =  "ID=" & DirectCast(dt.Rows(i)(0), Integer)

            Dim bs As New BindingSource(dv, Nothing)
            Dim db As New Binding("Checked", bs, "Selected")

            db.DataSourceUpdateMode = DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged
            cb.DataBindings.Add(db)

            Me.Controls.Add(cb)
        Next

        Dim btn As New Button()
        btn.Location = New Point(10, 30 * dt.Rows.Count)
        btn.Text = "Submit"
        AddHandler btn.Click, AddressOf Button1_Click
        Me.Controls.Add(btn)
    End Sub


    Private Sub Button1_Click( sender As Object,  e As EventArgs) 
        'Me.BindingContext(ds.Tables("Table1")).EndCurrentEdit() 'Doesn't cut the mustard!

        If ds.HasChanges()
            MessageBox.Show("Number of rows changed: " & ds.GetChanges().Tables("Table1").Rows.Count)
            ds.AcceptChanges()
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Number of rows changed: 0")
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

The key is the call to `EndEdit()` in the `ColumnChanged` event for `DataTable` (a general call to `EndCurrentEdit()` just doesn't appear to cut it), although one additional problem I encountered was that this code won't work if it's in the form's `New()` method, even if it's after the call to `InitializeComponent()`.  I'm guessing this is because there's some initialisation that Winforms does after the call to `New()` which is necessary for data binding to work properly.

I hope this example saves others the time I spent looking into this.

Comment: @RezaAghaei I had hoped it was pretty clear already, but I've added an extra sentence to the second paragraph for more clarity. EDIT: You keep updating your comment!  What grid?  There is no grid control here.

Comment: @RezaAghaei This is intended to be a simple functional example of the behaviour I'm experiencing.  The button calls `EndCurrentEdit()`.  In a larger project, this would be followed up by processing the data the user has entered.  I'm not doing anything with the data here because it is meaningless test data.  I'm not showing the controls in a grid because...why would I need to show them in a grid?

Comment: @RezaAghaei In reality the controls are generated dynamically, however that is not relevant to the example demonstrating the problem.  The code above is intended to be a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Nothing more.

Comment: *a general call to EndCurrentEdit() just doesn't appear to cut it* Surely calling `EndCurrentEdit` should be performed on correct currency manager. For each binding source you should call its `EndEdit` as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38718406/3110834), internally it makes `EndCurrentEdit` of correct currency manager be called and it make `EndEdit` of the correct `DataRowView` be called.

Comment: *one additional problem I encountered was that this code won't work if it's in the form's New() method, even if it's after the call to InitializeComponent().* It's because data-binding will not work before showing the form.  For more information see [Databinding doesn't work before Form Load - ComboBox Items initialized only after Form load](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38040403/3110834)

Comment: You can put your codes in form `Load` event. Then codes will work, but if for any reason you want to put them in constructor, it's enough to call `this.Show` or `this.Visible=true` after `InitializeComponent` and before your data-binding codes. Also as another workaround, you can force controls to be created. For more information take a look at this post. [How to print a Windows Form without showing/displaying it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37888268/3110834)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118906/discussion-between-interminable-and-reza-aghaei).

Comment: Let me know if you have any question about comments or linked answers or let me know if you found them useful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider these corrections and the problem will be solved:

- To bind a control to an specific index of a list, bind control to a binding source containing the list, and then set the Position of binding source to the specifixindex.
- When adding data-binding to `CheckBox` controls, set update mode to  `OnPropertyChanged`.
- Handle `CheckedChanged` event of `CheckBox` controls and call `Invalidate` method of grid to show changes in grid.
- In `CheckedChanged` also call `EndEdit` of the `BindingSource` which the `CheckBox` is bound to.
- Note: Call `EndEdit` usnig `BeginInvoke` to let all processes of checking the checkbox (including updating data source) be completed.

[image]

**C# Example**

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dt.Columns.Add("Id");
    dt.Columns.Add("Selected", typeof(bool));
    dt.Rows.Add("1", true);
    dt.Rows.Add("2", false);
    dt.Rows.Add("3", true);
    this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    var chekBoxes = new CheckBox[] { checkBox1, checkBox2, checkBox3 };
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        var bs = new BindingSource(dt, null);
        chekBoxes[i].DataBindings.Add("Checked", bs, "Selected",
            true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
        chekBoxes[i].CheckedChanged += (obj, arg) =>
        {
            this.dataGridView1.Invalidate();
            var c = (CheckBox)obj;
            var b = (BindingSource)(c.DataBindings[0].DataSource);
            this.BeginInvoke(()=>{b.EndEdit();});
        };
        bs.Position = i;
    }
}
```

**VB Example**

```vb
Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
Handles MyBase.Load
    dt.Columns.Add("Id")
    dt.Columns.Add("Selected", GetType(Boolean))
    dt.Rows.Add("1", True)
    dt.Rows.Add("2", False)
    dt.Rows.Add("3", True)
    dt.AcceptChanges()
    Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
    Dim chekBoxes = New CheckBox() {CheckBox1, CheckBox2, CheckBox3}
    For i = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
        Dim bs = New BindingSource(dt, Nothing)
        chekBoxes(i).DataBindings.Add("Checked", bs, "Selected", _
            True, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged)
        AddHandler chekBoxes(i).CheckedChanged, _
             Sub(obj, arg)
                 Me.DataGridView1.Invalidate()
                 Dim c = DirectCast(obj, CheckBox)
                 Dim b = DirectCast(c.DataBindings(0).DataSource, BindingSource)
                 Me.BeginInvoke(Sub() b.EndEdit())
             End Sub
        bs.Position = i
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your Answer, but it still experiences the same problem I have in my Question.  I have updated my Question again to try and make it even more clear what it is I am trying to do.

Comment: There is an screenshot in the post. Each checkbox is bound to a single row and it updates the `DataRow` immediately after check or uncheck. Isn't it what you are looking for? Can you say what's the problem with the answer?  Because based on my understanding from your question it completely answers your question. Did I miss anything?

Comment: Hello again, I didn't just use your screenshot, I also created a new Visual Studio project and tested your code, but I had to make some minor alterations to suit my requirements.  I will add the code I used to my question.  Also, please read the update to my question under the first **Edit**, it should help make things clear.

Comment: Hello :) OK, It seems I had missed `GetChanges`. Check the edited answer. If you get changed from data table, it returns rows which are changed and you can see their `RowState`.

Comment: By the way, to verify the answer, it's better to use exactly the codes of answer in a clean form containing a `DataGridView` and 3 `CheckBoxes`. You may encounter some problems in your test environment which are not related to the answer. The answer works properly in a clean environment.

Comment: As I noticed you have updated your Answer, I have refrained from posting updated code until I have finished testing your latest changes.

Comment: There are some important changes in the new code, **1-** I added `dt.AcceptChanges()` after adding rows manually. If you don't do it, all rows will be in Added State. **2-** After checking or unchecking the `CheckBox`, I called `EndEdit()` on it's `BindingSource`. It makes the edit end.

Comment: To test the result, it's enough to call `MessageBox.Show(dt.GetChanges().Rows.Count.ToString())` in a button.